# Quantitative Business Cycle Investing

Tags: research, mean-reversion, macro

Is there a major article or even better a comprehensive recent review article showing quantitative evidence for the existence of the business cycle and measuring the trending and mean reversion on that longer time scale.

Something on how to build portfolios around the cycle would be interesting as well, but I'm more interested currently if the cycle is a quantifiable (semi-) predictable effect.